# How to convert data to desired format and write to a file - Python + Apache Beam

Tags: python, json, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, ndjson

I have a `.ndjson` file looks like this:

```
{"property_id": "107", "transaction_unique_id": "{C3C3F9B5-FB9E-362B-E053-6B04A8C03ACC}", "price": 80000, "date_of_transfer": "2021-05-07 00:00", "postcode": "BL2 2GY", "property_type": "F", "old_new": "N", "duration": "L", "PAON": "14", "SAON": "", "street": "RIVER VIEW COURT", "locality": "", "town_city": "BOLTON", "district": "BOLTON", "country": "GREATER MANCHESTER", "PPD_category_type": "A", "record_status": "A"}
{"property_id": "108", "transaction_unique_id": "{C3C3F9B5-FB9F-362B-E053-6B04A8C03ACC}", "price": 330000, "date_of_transfer": "2021-02-26 00:00", "postcode": "SK6 4AN", "property_type": "S", "old_new": "N", "duration": "F", "PAON": "18", "SAON": "", "street": "GUYWOOD LANE", "locality": "ROMILEY", "town_city": "STOCKPORT", "district": "STOCKPORT", "country": "GREATER MANCHESTER", "PPD_category_type": "A", "record_status": "A"}
{"property_id": "109", "transaction_unique_id": "{C3C3F9B5-FBA0-362B-E053-6B04A8C03ACC}", "price": 215000, "date_of_transfer": "2021-02-19 00:00", "postcode": "M1 2BL", "property_type": "F", "old_new": "N", "duration": "L", "PAON": "40", "SAON": "APARTMENT 022", "street": "HILTON STREET", "locality": "", "town_city": "MANCHESTER", "district": "MANCHESTER", "country": "GREATER MANCHESTER", "PPD_category_type": "A", "record_status": "A"}
{"property_id": "109", "transaction_unique_id": "{C3C3F9B5-FBD3-362B-E053-6B04A8C03ACC}", "price": 226500, "date_of_transfer": "2021-02-08 00:00", "postcode": "M1 2BL", "property_type": "F", "old_new": "N", "duration": "L", "PAON": "40", "SAON": "APARTMENT 727", "street": "HILTON STREET", "locality": "", "town_city": "MANCHESTER", "district": "MANCHESTER", "country": "GREATER MANCHESTER", "PPD_category_type": "A", "record_status": "A"}
{"property_id": "109", "transaction_unique_id": "{C3C3F9B5-FBF8-362B-E053-6B04A8C03ACC}", "price": 262000, "date_of_transfer": "2021-05-14 00:00", "postcode": "M1 2BL", "property_type": "F", "old_new": "N", "duration": "L", "PAON": "40", "SAON": "APARTMENT 025", "street": "HILTON STREET", "locality": "", "town_city": "MANCHESTER", "district": "MANCHESTER", "country": "GREATER MANCHESTER", "PPD_category_type": "A", "record_status": "A"}
...
```

I used Apache Beam to read it and grouped the data by `property_id`, then I wrote the output to a json file, but the data looks like this:

```
('107', [PPD(property_id='107', transaction_unique_id='{C3C3F9B5-FB9E-362B-E053-6B04A8C03ACC}', price=80000, date_of_transfer='2021-05-07 00:00', postcode='BL2 2GY', property_type='F', old_new='N', duration='L', PAON='14', SAON='', street='RIVER VIEW COURT', locality='', town_city='BOLTON', district='BOLTON', country='GREATER MANCHESTER', PPD_category_type='A', record_status='A')])
('108', [PPD(property_id='108', transaction_unique_id='{C3C3F9B5-FB9F-362B-E053-6B04A8C03ACC}', price=330000, date_of_transfer='2021-02-26 00:00', postcode='SK6 4AN', property_type='S', old_new='N', duration='F', PAON='18', SAON='', street='GUYWOOD LANE', locality='ROMILEY', town_city='STOCKPORT', district='STOCKPORT', country='GREATER MANCHESTER', PPD_category_type='A', record_status='A')])
('109', [PPD(property_id='109', transaction_unique_id='{C3C3F9B5-FBA0-362B-E053-6B04A8C03ACC}', price=215000, date_of_transfer='2021-02-19 00:00', postcode='M1 2BL', property_type='F', old_new='N', duration='L', PAON='40', SAON='APARTMENT 022', street='HILTON STREET', locality='', town_city='MANCHESTER', district='MANCHESTER', country='GREATER MANCHESTER', PPD_category_type='A', record_status='A'), PPD(property_id='109', transaction_unique_id='{C3C3F9B5-FBD3-362B-E053-6B04A8C03ACC}', price=226500, date_of_transfer='2021-02-08 00:00', postcode='M1 2BL', property_type='F', old_new='N', duration='L', PAON='40', SAON='APARTMENT 727', street='HILTON STREET', locality='', town_city='MANCHESTER', district='MANCHESTER', country='GREATER MANCHESTER', PPD_category_type='A', record_status='A'), PPD(property_id='109', transaction_unique_id='{C3C3F9B5-FBF8-362B-E053-6B04A8C03ACC}', price=262000, date_of_transfer='2021-05-14 00:00', postcode='M1 2BL', property_type='F', old_new='N', duration='L', PAON='40', SAON='APARTMENT 025', street='HILTON STREET', locality='', town_city='MANCHESTER', district='MANCHESTER', country='GREATER MANCHESTER', PPD_category_type='A', record_status='A')])
...
```

We can see that for `property_id = '109'`, it grouped three records, but the output format above is really weird...Does anything know why is that and how can I convert it to a newline delimited JSON format and then write to a JSON file?

Expected format looks something like (not sure if this is valid newline delimited json format, but the idea is to include the transactions for the same `property_id` (for example `109`) in an array):

```
{"property_id": "107", "transaction_unique_id": "{C3C3F9B5-FB9E-362B-E053-6B04A8C03ACC}", "price": 80000, "date_of_transfer": "2021-05-07 00:00", "postcode": "BL2 2GY", "property_type": "F", "old_new": "N", "duration": "L", "PAON": "14", "SAON": "", "street": "RIVER VIEW COURT", "locality": "", "town_city": "BOLTON", "district": "BOLTON", "country": "GREATER MANCHESTER", "PPD_category_type": "A", "record_status": "A"}
{"property_id": "108", "transaction_unique_id": "{C3C3F9B5-FB9F-362B-E053-6B04A8C03ACC}", "price": 330000, "date_of_transfer": "2021-02-26 00:00", "postcode": "SK6 4AN", "property_type": "S", "old_new": "N", "duration": "F", "PAON": "18", "SAON": "", "street": "GUYWOOD LANE", "locality": "ROMILEY", "town_city": "STOCKPORT", "district": "STOCKPORT", "country": "GREATER MANCHESTER", "PPD_category_type": "A", "record_status": "A"}
{"property_id": "109", "transactions": [{"transaction_unique_id": "{C3C3F9B5-FBA0-362B-E053-6B04A8C03ACC}", "price": 215000, "date_of_transfer": "2021-02-19 00:00", "postcode": "M1 2BL", "property_type": "F", "old_new": "N", "duration": "L", "PAON": "40", "SAON": "APARTMENT 022", "street": "HILTON STREET", "locality": "", "town_city": "MANCHESTER", "district": "MANCHESTER", "country": "GREATER MANCHESTER", "PPD_category_type": "A", "record_status": "A"},{"transaction_unique_id": "{C3C3F9B5-FBD3-362B-E053-6B04A8C03ACC}", "price": 226500, "date_of_transfer": "2021-02-08 00:00", "postcode": "M1 2BL", "property_type": "F", "old_new": "N", "duration": "L", "PAON": "40", "SAON": "APARTMENT 727", "street": "HILTON STREET", "locality": "", "town_city": "MANCHESTER", "district": "MANCHESTER", "country": "GREATER MANCHESTER", "PPD_category_type": "A", "record_status": "A"},{"transaction_unique_id": "{C3C3F9B5-FBF8-362B-E053-6B04A8C03ACC}", "price": 262000, "date_of_transfer": "2021-05-14 00:00", "postcode": "M1 2BL", "property_type": "F", "old_new": "N", "duration": "L", "PAON": "40", "SAON": "APARTMENT 025", "street": "HILTON STREET", "locality": "", "town_city": "MANCHESTER", "district": "MANCHESTER", "country": "GREATER MANCHESTER", "PPD_category_type": "A", "record_status": "A"}]}
...
```

Can someone help please, I'm very new to beam, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `PPD` is a named tuple and you're taking a PCollection of `PPD` objects and grouping them like

```
grouped = (
    ppd_pcoll
    | beam.Map(lambda ppd: (ppd.property_id, property_id)
    | beam.GroupByKey())
```

Now `grouped` is a PCollection of 2-tuples, where the first is the property id string, and the second is an iterable of PPDs (with that property id).

In order to get what you want, you'll need to map it to the desired dictionary to output it as json, e.g.

```
to_write_to_json = (grouped
 | beam.MapTuple(lambda property_id, ppds: {
      'property_id': property_id,
      'transactions': [ppd_to_transaction(ppd) for ppd in ppds],
     })
```

where `ppd_to_transaction` is a function that takes your PPD object and returns a dict with the desired transaction properties.

Comment: Do you mind provide some code for `ppd_to_transaction` function? I'm not sure how to takes a PPD object and returns a dict with the desired transaction properties...

Comment: Something like

def ppd_to_transaction(ppd): return {'transaction_unique_id': ppd. transaction_unique_id, 'price"; ppd.price, ...} possibly using getattr and friends to enumerate the fields programmatically rather than typing them all out if that's easier.